# Bulk update using self join in Oracle

Tags: sql, oracle

I want to bulk update some rows in same table. I have a table, let's say TABLEA, having columns `Id` and `OriginalID`. I want to write a query with a combination of inner joins with some other tables:

```
Update TABLEA 
SET OriginalID = Id 
FROM TABLEA A
INNER JOIN TableB B ON <join condition>
INNER JOIN TableC C ON <join condition>
WHERE c.SomeCol = <value>
```

This works for SQL Server 2005 and for Oracle, it gives error

> SQL Error: ORA-00933: SQL command not properly ended.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Other solutions:

1. Updatable views:

   ```
   UPDATE (SELECT OriginalID, ID FROM TABLEA A 
   INNER JOIN TableB B ON <join condition> 
   INNER JOIN TableC C ON <join condition> 
   WHERE c.SomeCol = <value> 
   )  
   SET OriginalID = Id;
   ```
2. You could also use MERGE statement.

   ```
   MERGE INTO TableA USING
   (SELECT <used columns, ids> 
   FROM TableB B
   INNER JOIN TableC C ON <join condition> 
   WHERE c.SomeCol = <value>)
   ON (<join condition beteen A and B>)
   WHEN MATCHED THEN 
   UPDATE SET
   OriginalID = ID;
   ```

Comment: If you add the Merge query(a valid query), I'll vote you up. Please add a comment here after you've done it.

Comment: @FlorinGhita just fyi, the merge query has been added

Answer (score 1):

I believe you want something like this .

```
UPDATE tableA a
   SET OriginalID = (SELECT a2.id
                       FROM tableA a2 
                            JOIN tableB b ON (<<join between a,b,and a2>>)
                            JOIN tableC c ON (<<join between b,and c>>)
                      WHERE c.SomeCol = <<value>>)
 WHERE EXISTS( SELECT 1
                 FROM tableA a2 
                      JOIN tableB b ON (<<join between a,b,and a2>>)
                      JOIN tableC c ON (<<join between b,and c>>)
                WHERE c.SomeCol = <<value>>)
```

Comment: no Id is not a column of tableB it is column of tableA itself

Comment: @user1049021 - If you are stating that you need to update the `OriginalID` column in `tableA` to an `id` column from a different row in `tableA`, I updated my answer.  It's always helpful to post an example of your data and the expected output to make things more clear.